# WCS 7.0 and Sterling integration Issue

Tags: web-services, websphere-7, websphere-commerce, wcs

We are trying to integrate the WebSphere commerce 7.0 (Feature Pack 4) and Sterling (DOM) system. We followed the steps mentioned in the IBM infocenter. BUt we are getting the below exception when we are trying to GetProductAvailability.

Our wc-component-client.xml is similar to below, 
Path :  workspace\WC\xml\config\com.ibm.commerce.inventory.external

```
<_config:action name="GetProductAvailability" asynchronous="false">
        <_config:preinvokemediator
            mediatorImpl="com.ibm.commerce.foundation.services.invocation.internal.impl.JSPMessageInvocationMediatorImpl">
            <_config:property name="url"
                value="http://localhost:80/webapp/wcs/stores/IBM.WC.Compose/mediation/SterlingCommerce/GetProductAvailabilityRequestMediator.jsp" />
        </_config:preinvokemediator>
        <_config:postinvokemediator
            mediatorImpl="com.ibm.commerce.foundation.services.invocation.internal.impl.JSPMessageInvocationMediatorImpl">
            <_config:property name="url"
                value="http://localhost:80/webapp/wcs/stores/IBM.WC.Compose/mediation/SterlingCommerce/GetProductAvailabilityResponseMediator.jsp" />
        </_config:postinvokemediator>
    </_config:action>
```

And the exception which we are getting while checking for inventory is

```
0000003f commands      I com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.server.commands.ComposeDOMInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl callGetInventoryAvailabilityService CWXFR0031E: Failed to read the file "wc-component-client.xml" due to "com.ibm.commerce.foundation.services.invocation.internal.impl.JSPMessageInvocationMediatorImpl incompatible with com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.spi.MessageInvocationMediator".
                             com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.exception.ComponentConfigurationException: CWXFR0031E: Failed to read the file "wc-component-client.xml" due to "com.ibm.commerce.foundation.services.invocation.internal.impl.JSPMessageInvocationMediatorImpl incompatible with com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.spi.MessageInvocationMediator".
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfiguration.loadConfigServices(ComponentConfiguration.java:452)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfiguration.initialize(ComponentConfiguration.java:205)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfiguration.<init>(ComponentConfiguration.java:124)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.loadComponentConfiguration(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:293)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfigurationRegistry.getComponentConfiguration(ComponentConfigurationRegistry.java:258)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.impl.DefaultInvocationServiceSourceImpl.getComponentConfiguration(DefaultInvocationServiceSourceImpl.java:65)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.impl.DefaultInvocationServiceSourceImpl.getAction(DefaultInvocationServiceSourceImpl.java:145)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.InvocationServiceFactory.createAction(InvocationServiceFactory.java:107)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.InvocationService.invoke(InvocationService.java:76)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.client.facade.bod.AbstractBusinessObjectDocumentFacadeClient.sendBusinessObjectDocument(AbstractBusinessObjectDocumentFacadeClient.java:421)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.client.ExternalInventoryFacadeClient.getInventoryAvailability(ExternalInventoryFacadeClient.java:91)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.server.commands.ComposeDOMInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl.callGetInventoryAvailabilityService(ComposeDOMInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl.java:343)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.server.commands.ComposeDOMInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl.getInventoryAvailabilityFromDOM(ComposeDOMInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl.java:320)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.server.commands.ComposeDOMInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl.execute(ComposeDOMInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl.java:990)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.server.commands.FetchInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl.performExecute(FetchInventoryAvailabilityCmdImpl.java:1468)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.server.command.impl.CommandTarget.executeCommand(CommandTarget.java:66)
at com.ibm.websphere.command.TargetableCommandImpl.execute(TargetableCommandImpl.java:139)
at com.ibm.websphere.command.CacheableCommandImpl.execute(CacheableCommandImpl.java:138)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.command.bod.AbstractGetBusinessObjectDocumentCmdImpl.performExpression(AbstractGetBusinessObjectDocumentCmdImpl.java:282)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.command.bod.AbstractGetBusinessObjectDocumentCmdImpl.performExecute(AbstractGetBusinessObjectDocumentCmdImpl.java:145)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.command.bod.BusinessObjectCommandTargetImpl.executeCommand(BusinessObjectCommandTargetImpl.java:112)
at com.ibm.websphere.command.TargetableCommandImpl.execute(TargetableCommandImpl.java:139)
at com.ibm.websphere.command.CacheableCommandImpl.execute(CacheableCommandImpl.java:138)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.server.command.bod.BusinessObjectDocumentProcessor.processBusinessObjectDocument(BusinessObjectDocumentProcessor.java:199)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.server.InventoryFacadeImpl.getInventoryAvailability(InventoryFacadeImpl.java:49)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.server.EJSLocalStatelessInventory_65d6ce99.getInventoryAvailability(EJSLocalStatelessInventory_65d6ce99.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.impl.LocalEJBInvocationBindingImpl.invoke(LocalEJBInvocationBindingImpl.java:173)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.InvocationService.invoke(InvocationService.java:113)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.client.facade.bod.AbstractBusinessObjectDocumentFacadeClient.sendBusinessObjectDocument(AbstractBusinessObjectDocumentFacadeClient.java:421)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.client.AbstractInventoryFacadeClient.getInventoryAvailability(AbstractInventoryFacadeClient.java:130)
at com.ibm.commerce.inventory.facade.client.AbstractInventoryFacadeClient.getInventoryAvailability(AbstractInventoryFacadeClient.java:281)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.taglib.config.GetDataConfig$DataTypeConfig.invokeClientFacadeMethod(GetDataConfig.java:863)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.taglib.GetDataHandler.execute(GetDataHandler.java:733)
at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.taglib.GetDataTag.doTag(GetDataTag.java:388)
at com.ibm._jsp._CatalogEntryInventoryStatus._jspService(_CatalogEntryInventoryStatus.java:786)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:375)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:211)
at com.ibm._jsp._CachedProductOnlyDisplay._jspx_meth_c_import_1(_CachedProductOnlyDisplay.java:11982)
at com.ibm._jsp._CachedProductOnlyDisplay._jspService(_CachedProductOnlyDisplay.java:1367)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:375)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:211)
at com.ibm._jsp._ProductDisplay._jspx_meth_c_import_5(_ProductDisplay.java:7139)
at com.ibm._jsp._ProductDisplay._jspService(_ProductDisplay.java:1188)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:354)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.processRequest(ECActionServlet.java:215)
at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.doGet(ECActionServlet.java:157)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at com.ibm.commerce.campaigns.filter.CampaignsFilter.doFilter(CampaignsFilter.java:148)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.commerce.likeminds.filter.LikeMindsFilter.doFilter(LikeMindsFilter.java:183)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter$2.run(CacheFilter.java:376)
at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilterAction(RuntimeServletFilter.java:367)
at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.access$0(RuntimeServletFilter.java:247)
at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter$1.run(RuntimeServletFilter.java:210)
at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilter(RuntimeServletFilter.java:231)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.services.invocation.internal.impl.JSPMessageInvocationMediatorImpl incompatible with com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.spi.MessageInvocationMediator
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.metadata.InvocationServiceConfiguration.getMessageInvocationMediator(InvocationServiceConfiguration.java:175)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.services.invocation.metadata.InvocationServiceConfiguration.parseElement(InvocationServiceConfiguration.java:106)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.common.config.node.AbstractConfigNodeImpl.load(AbstractConfigNodeImpl.java:78)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.common.config.AbstractServiceConfigurationImpl.loadConfig(AbstractServiceConfigurationImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.common.config.ComponentConfiguration.loadConfigServices(ComponentConfiguration.java:445)
    ... 140 more

Comment: We are doing a web-service call to Sterling system.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the wrong version of JSPMessageInvocationMediatorImpl try the one with client in the package name.  com.ibm.commerce.foundation.services.internal.client.services.invocation.impl.JSPMessageInvocationMediatorImpl

Answer (score 0):

I got this working on my desktop but following the instructions. Still I would contact IBM Software Support.